# How to find a numeric value within a range in php

Tags: php

How can I find a value let: 745 is within a range of 0 to 1000 using php?

Comment: You should specify what you mean, when writing "find a value". In array? Check if it's exists? Some explain please.

Answer (score 7):

```
(0 <= $value && $value <= 1000)
```

Comment: There is also, `in_array($num, range(0, 1000));` or `$range = range(0, 1000); if(isset($range[$num))` .. But, @Matti's solution is better.

Comment: @Russell: ...yes, however that creates a new array and then does a linear search in it for no reason whatsoever. The answer with that already got deleted by the owner. (And I wonder who downvoted me)

Comment: Yeah, of course this solution is much better. Hence why I didn't bother with an answer. Not sure about the downvote, I only have one downvote and that one deserved it :P

Answer (score 1):

How about using `<=` and `>=` ?

```
$x=745;
$inrange=(0<=$x)&&($x<=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a condition

```
<?php
$val = 745;
if ($val >= 0 && $val <= 1000)
{
  // Ok
}
else
{
 // Not ok
}
```